# SPSS analysis: repeated design for total sum DVs

Tags: repeated-measures, spss

I am trying to run an SPSS analysis on two dependent variables (DVs) that are part of a total group of DVs that sum to 1. That is, my research question was how people spend their time on one of the three activity categories, and I asked them to indicate the proportion of their time spent on each of these activities: A, B or C. The total should sum up to 100%.

My hypothesis is that people spend a greater proportion of their time on A than on B. But as you can see, A and B are not independent from each other, such that A+B+C always adds up to 100%. Is it okay to run an SPSS repeated measure analysis: having 2 factors? IF this is not a good idea, what is a better approach?